# How to "break" a JSON tree in down into separate lists starting from the parent down to each child connected in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON which the children could have more child objects:

```
{
    "color": "red",
    "list": [{
            "color": "blue",
            "list": [{
                "color": "yellow"
            }, {
                "color": "black",
                "list": [{
                    "color": "purple"
                }, {
                    "color": "white"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "color": "green",
            "list": [{
                "color": "pink",
                "list": [{
                    "color": "gray"
                }, {
                    "color": "brown"
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

from the following tree:

[COLOR TREE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws1yG.png)

I want to break down the diagram into separate lists from the parent down to each child connected:

```
LIST1 = red,blue
LIST2 = red,blue,yellow
LIST3 = red,blue,black
LIST4 = red,blue,black,purple
LIST5 = red,blue,black,white
LIST6 = red,green
LIST7 = red,green,pink
LIST8 = red,green,pink,grey
LIST9 = red,green,pink,brown
```

Comment: Use recursion. For a given object and list of colors already traversed, add the color of the object to the list and recurse for each object of the children list with a copy of the colors list.

Comment: You can use any library like jackson or gson to read the json in java and try writing the code yourself to generate separate lists. Update the question with your code if you face any issue.

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting one, tried to solve this. Please, let me know, if the solution helps. I have implemented this in Java.

```
// Java program to print all the node to leaf path    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child
       and a pointer to right child */
class Color {

    private String color;
    private List<Color> list;

    public Color() {
        //default
    }

    public Color(String color) {
        this.color = color;
        list = new ArrayList();
    }

    public Color(String color, List<Color> list) {
        this.color = color;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void add(Color c) {
        this.list.add(c);
    }

    public void setList(List<Color> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public List<Color> getList() {
        return this.list;
    }
}

class ColorTree {
    Color root;

    /*Given a binary tree, print out all of its root-to-leaf
      paths, one per line. Uses a recursive helper to do
      the work.*/
    void printPaths(Color node) {
        String[] path = new String[1000];
        printPathsRecur(node, path, 0);
    }

    /* Recursive helper function -- given a node, and an array
       containing the path from the root node up to but not
       including this node, print out all the root-leaf paths.*/
    void printPathsRecur(Color node, String[] path, int pathLen) {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        /* append this node to the path array */
        path[pathLen] = node.getColor();
        pathLen++;
        printArray(path, pathLen);

        /* it's a leaf, so print the path that led to here  */
        if (node.getList() == null || node.getList().size() == 0) {
            //printArray(path, pathLen);
        } else {
            Iterator<Color> colorIter = node.getList().iterator();
            /* otherwise try subtrees */
            while (colorIter.hasNext()) {
                printPathsRecur(colorIter.next(), path, pathLen);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Utility function that prints out an array on a line. */
    void printArray(String[] names, int len) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.print(names[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    private static Color convertJsonToColor(String input) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        return mapper.readValue(input, Color.class);
    }

    // driver program to test above functions
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonInput = "{ \"color\": \"red\", \"list\": [{ \"color\": \"blue\", \"list\": [{ \"color\": \"yellow\" }, { \"color\": \"black\", \"list\": [{ \"color\": \"purple\" }, { \"color\": \"white\" }] }] }, { \"color\": \"green\", \"list\": [{ \"color\": \"pink\", \"list\": [{ \"color\": \"gray\" }, { \"color\": \"brown\" }] }] } ] }";

        ColorTree tree = new ColorTree();
        tree.root = convertJsonToColor(jsonInput);

        /* Let us test the built tree by printing Insorder traversal */
        tree.printPaths(tree.root);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Ana, I've been on this for a few days now, my version of self recursion is far from this.